# Using Terraform resource okta_group_assignments resource with Okta Terraform provider to loop through both apps and group ids

Tags: okta, terraform-provider

I need help with the Okta Terraform provider to clean up my code. I want to map which apps have been created to the groups it needs for resource `okta_app_group_assignments`. My code is the following:

vars.tf

```
variable "app_group_assignments" {
  description = "Mapping of app names to groups"
  type        = list(object({
    app_name  = string
    groups    = list(string)
  }))
  default = [
    {
      app_name = "cisco_meraki_app",
      groups   = ["foo"]
    },
    {
      app_name = "freshworks_app",
      groups   = ["group1", "eng"]
    },
  ]
}
```

group_assignments.tf

```
resource "okta_app_group_assignments" "dynamic_assignments" {
  for_each = { for assignment in var.app_group_assignments : assignment.app_name => assignment }

  app_id = okta_app_saml[each.key].id

  dynamic "group" {
    for_each = { for group_name in each.value.groups : group_name => group_name }
    content {
      id       = okta_group.group[group.key].id
      priority = index(each.value.groups, group.key) + 1
    }
  }
}
```

I expected this to work for myself but I always got this error:

```
│ Error: Invalid reference
│ 
│   on group_app_assignments.tf line 4, in resource "okta_app_group_assignments" "dynamic_assignments":
│    4:   app_id = okta_app_saml[each.key].id
│ 
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.
```

Is my best bet to either loop through my apps and assign the group or reference the `app_id` and loop through which groups to assign to? Would appreciate any help.